# Issue in django when regrouping by date

Tags: python, django, datetime, unicode

I will try to specify as detailed as possible the context where I come across this issue.

Model:

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    project = models.ForeignKey(ProjectSchedule, related_name='schedules')
    person = models.ForeignKey(PersonSchedule, related_name='schedules')
    week_date = models.DateField() # first day of the week
    hours = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['project']
        unique_together = ('project', 'person', 'week_date')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode("%s from %s schedule (%shs)" % (self.person, self.project, self.hours))
```

View:

```
class ReportView(TemplateView):
    start_year = None
    start_month = None
    start_day = None
    start_week = None

    end_year = None
    end_month = None
    end_day = None
    end_week = None

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.start_year = int(kwargs.get('start_year'))
            self.start_month = int(kwargs.get('start_month'))
            self.start_day = int(kwargs.get('start_day'))
            self.start_week = datetime.date(self.start_year, self.start_month, self.start_day)

            self.end_year = int(kwargs.get('end_year'))
            self.end_month = int(kwargs.get('end_month'))
            self.end_day = int(kwargs.get('end_day'))
            self.end_week = datetime.date(self.end_year, self.end_month, self.end_day)

    def get_schedules(self):
        return Schedule.objects.filter(week_date__range=[self.start_week, self.end_week])

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProjectsReportTableView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({'schedules': self.get_schedules()})
        return context
```

Template:

```
<h2>Schedules by week</h2>

{% regroup schedules by week_date as schedules_grouped_by_week %}
{% for week_schedules_group in schedules_grouped_by_week %}
    <h3>{{ week_schedules_group.grouper }}</h3>
    <p>{{ week_schedules_group.list }}</p>
{% endfor %}
<br/>

<h3>All schedules regrouped</h3>
<p>{{ schedules_grouped_by_week }}</p>
```

Result:

```
Schedules by week

June 23, 2014 <------ SAME
[<Schedule: Kelian from Oxford schedule (1hs)>]

June 2, 2014
[<Schedule: [Bad Unicode data]>, <Schedule: [Bad Unicode data]>]

June 23, 2014 <------ SAME
[<Schedule: Rodrigo from Influester schedule (56hs)>]

June 9, 2014
[<Schedule: [Bad Unicode data]>]


All schedules regrouped     
[{u'list': [<Schedule: Kelian from Oxford schedule (1hs)>], u'grouper': datetime.date(2014, 6, 23)}, <---SAME
 {u'list': [<Schedule: [Bad Unicode data]>, <Schedule: [Bad Unicode data]>], u'grouper': datetime.date(2014, 6, 2)},
 {u'list': [<Schedule: Rodrigo from Influester schedule (56hs)>], u'grouper': datetime.date(2014, 6, 23)}, <---SAME
 {u'list': [<Schedule: [Bad Unicode data]>], u'grouper': datetime.date(2014, 6, 9)}]
```

Note:

The bad unicode thing is because of the special characters of my native language (spanish). Or there is an issue regrouping by datetime.date() objects or there is an issue around some unicode/regrouping thing (note that those schedules with "Bad Unicode data" are correctly grouped, don't now why). I found very few people with this problem in forums/stack overflow/google groups but they were grouping but their models had as date a datetime object (date = models.DateTimeField()) so every date with difference of seconds get grouped separately, they got their issue fixed by grouping by date.date, but this is not my case, I'm dealing exclusively with datetime.date() objects all along the code as you can see.

I'm using django 1.6.5 and python 2.7.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup):

> Note that `{% regroup %}` does not order its input.

(In this sense, it's like `uniq` or `itertools.groupby`.)

If you order the results of get_schedules, you should get the correct results:

```
def get_schedules(self):
    schedules = Schedule.objects.filter(week_date__range=[self.start_week, self.end_week])
    schedules = schedules.order_by('week_date')
    return schedules
```